# Pass an extended class by parameter

Tags: php, class, polymorphism

I have a parent classes:

```
namespace classes;
abstract class MyParent{ abstract function name(); }
```

Now, two children:

```
namespace classes;
class Foo extends MyParent{ function name(){ return "Foo class"; } }

namespace classes;
class Bar extends MyParent{ function name(){ return "Bar class"; } }
```

In java, I can do this:

```
public void doSomething(AnObject <?extends MyParent?> object){ }
```

The method above can recive all objects that are extended from MyParent class. How can I achive this in php?  Of course, declaring the function simply like `function doSomething($child){}` does the trick, but I want to specify the type of object like:

```
function doSomething(classes\{any-children-of-MyParent} $class){}
```

If I do `function doSomething(classes\MyParent $class){}` and pass it an instance of `Foo` class I get this error:

> Argument 1 passed to doSomething must be an instance of
>   clasess\MyParent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like this.

```
public function doSomething(\clases\MyParent $object){ }
                         // ^ namespace from the root.
```

It's called [type hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Demo: http://3v4l.org/tqV3s

Comment: At least it is possible as your demo confirm it. Should be a problem with my app logic! Thank you so much!

Comment: Just to clarfy, you was correct! I was passing another class type out of scope (not a children).  :)

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track, @manix.

In PHP, it is exactly the same. If you wish to have any class extending a parent class in a method, simply give the name of the class before the object name. As @sectus said, this is what we call [type-hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

The problem you seem to have is a namespace issue. Concerning namespaces, you need to know that if you already are in a namespace in your script, and you don't prefix the class name with a backslash (`\`), the namespace will be resolved relatively to your current namespace.

This means that if you are in

```
namespace Foo;
```

The following piece of code will interpret `Bar` as being part of the `Foo` namespace.

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

class Bar
{
    public function doSomething(Bar $bar)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So if you have another class in the same namespace

```
<?php

namespace Foo;

class Baz extends Bar
{
    public function doSomething(Bar $bar)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You don't need to specify the namespace once again. On the other hand, if your class was in another namespace (let's say `Quz`), `Bar` would be resolved as `Quz\Bar`, which is not defined yet.

```
<?php

namespace Quz;

class Baz extends Bar
{
    public function doSomething(Bar $bar)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To fix this, you need to either:

- import the namespace with a `use` statement
- use an absolute reference to the `Foo\Bar` class

  namespace Quz;

  use Foo\Bar;

  class Baz extends Bar
  {
      public function doSomething(Bar $bar)
      {
          // ...
      }
  }

or

```
<?php

namespace Quz;

class Baz extends \Foo\Bar
{
    public function doSomething(\Foo\Bar $bar)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The principle is exactly the same for arguments inside a class' methods. Oh, and by the way, if you take a look at the code here, you may see that you may totally do something like

```
<?php

$quz = new Quz\Baz();
$baz = new Foo\Baz();
$bar = new Foo\Bar();

$bar->doSomething($quz);
$bar->doSomething($bar);
$bar->doSomething($baz);

$quz->doSomething($quz);
$quz->doSomething($bar);
$quz->doSomething($baz);

$baz->doSomething($quz);
$baz->doSomething($bar);
$baz->doSomething($baz);
```

Comment: Your explanation is really perfect. Apologies for do not be allowed to accept two answers. I really apreciate your help